# Java method access on runtime polymorphism

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, dynamic-dispatch

I have the following java code.

```
class A {

        public void method1() {
            System.out.println("A 1");
            method2();
        }

        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("A 2");
        }

    }

    class B extends A {
        @Override
        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("B 2");
        }
    }

    public class Tester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a = new B();
            a.method1();
        }
    }
```

It prints

```
    A 1
    B 2
```

- What exactly happens at runtime when a.method1() is called?
- How is the derived method getting called from the parent?
- Is it looking at the object and the method name string and calling
  the method during runtime?
- Is it calling this.method2() by default?

Comment: @AluanHaddad If you have a close look at Class A's method1, it called method2 inside of it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am running it on my eclipse IDE, Its printing A 1 B 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the method `method1(...)` was never overridden, B inherits A's `method1()` and it is called as if it were defined in B.

Since `method1()` calls `method2()` the overridden method `method2()` defined in B is called, when the instance was created with the B constructor.

If you create another instance, with the A constructor, you will not get the overridden `method2(...)` defined in B, but get the original `method2(...)` defined in A.

Comment: So, The behaviour is due to the instance. For our current Instance, method2() means the overridden method2()?

Comment: Yes, every non-static method in Java is looked up based on the instance.  If you change instances, you might get the same method; because they might resolve to the same block of code; but, if one of the instances resolves back to an overridden method, the first block of code matching that method as you move up the inheritance tree is typically used.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly happens at runtime when a.method1() is called?

method1() of Class A called.

> How is the derived method getting called from the parent?

Since you have ovverided the method, `method2` in class B, that will be the method which is going to be called at runtime.

> Is it looking at the object and the method name string and calling the method during runtime?

Don't get confuse here. When you write

```
 A a = new B();
```

Methods from Class B gets called if they are ovveridden otherwise from A gets called.

> Is it calling this.method2() by default?

Again, it is not defaulting. If you ovveride it gets called from B. If you don't ovveride, it gets called from A

Answer (score 0):

Because your object is actually of type `B` that is inheriting from `A`. inside your `B`'s class you're overriding method2 that is why it is calling `B.method2()`

```
  A a = new B();
```

To call `method2` from `A`, use:

```
  A a = new A();
```

Answer (score 0):

When object of type B is initialized it is an instance of class B even though it is implicitly cast to an object of type A.

Hence when you call `a.method1()` since `method1()` is not defined in class B it calls the method defined in the base class. Then in turn when `method2()` is called it is defined in class B and since the object is of type B the method in class B is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You have created Object of Child class and an Object of type Reference.
The reference is of type Parent (Down-casting)

When you call any method on reference, the method of type reference will be invoked. But in case the method is not available in reference type, it will be called from Parent (Inheritance).

In your example compiler checks for a method1 in object A and finds it there.
Second when method2 is called its invoked from the current Object (Object B instead of from Reference A).

Note since the method2 is overriden when you call it from reference of A it will invoke method from Object A (Parent) and if you invoke it from Reference B it will invoke from Object B(Child).

Key point to remember here is the difference in Reference and Object. They both are different entities.

*The same thing will happen if you call a concrete method from abstract class which calls an abstract method of same class. The child class's implementation method will get called.